# Chain two redux actions and use the updated state in the second one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I think that I'm stuck on a simple problem, for which I might also have a solution but I'm not aware about the "quality" of my idea.

Basically, in my state I have an array property which I need to update right before dispatching another action.

Let's assume that my state is something like this:

```js
const state = {
    arrayProperty: []
}
```

I have a simple action like this:

```js
const ADD_VALUE = "ADD_VALUE"
const addValue = value => ({
    type: ADD_VALUE,
    value
})
```

In response to this action, in my reducer I just have something like:

```js
...
case ADD_VALUE:
    return update(state, { arrayProperty: { $push: [action.value] }})
...
```

I also have an action that sync this state with the server, something like this (obviously I skipped some parts):

```js
const SAVE = "SAVE"
const save = model => dispatch =>
    API
      .save(model)
      .then(
          response => dispatch(saved(response))
      )

const SAVED = "SAVED"
const saved = response => ({
    type: SAVED,
    response
})
```

My problem is that I would like to call both the previous actions, but I don't know how to get the updated state after the first one, and passing it to the second one.

I tried this (and it worked), but I am not sure if this is the proper way of doing it:

```js
const addValueAndSave = value => (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(addValue(value))
    dispatch(save(getState()))
}
```

Ending up to my question... is this the right way for doing this?

Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you are doing it right! With `thunks` by the time you want to dispatch your `save` action, calling `getState` will fetch the latest state which is exactly what you want. Now just for the sake of it you could make the whole thing one action only that is asynchronous. So you can do optimistic updates and revert them if your API call fails (if that's the desired behavior). Just to give you an example:

```
function addValue(value) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_VALUE,
      value,
    });

    API.save(getState()).catch(() => {
      alert('Something went wrong, try again later.');
      dispatch({
        type: REMOVE_VALUE,
        value,
      });
    });
  };
}
```

Or alternatively you can even have create a middleware that does that for you for specific actions but that's a completely different thing. I hope I could give you some perspective on your options but overall you are doing it right ;)